# System type to install program from source

Tags: 16.04, system, source

I need to install a program from source code and during the installation it asks for "system type (? for a list) [gnu]:" When I press ? to see the list I get the following:

```
sgi, sgi-debug, sgi-mips3, sun, sun-static, sun-debug, dec, dec-debug
dec-prof, dec-gprof, gnu, gnu-debug, portland, portland, portland-ebug
hp, ibm, cray, nec
```

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Yoga 211 with a Intel PENTIUM processor. How can you tell the "system type" I should use from the list?

Comment: It is `gnu`. See for yourself: `uname -o`. Ubuntu is a distribution of GNU/Linux.

Comment: Thanks! I compiled it using `gnu` but when I try to run it I get `bash: /home/david/bin/cofima: /bin/ksh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: `ksh` (the Korn shell) is not installed by default in Ubuntu - if the software requires `ksh`, you will need to install it  - or modify the script(s) so that they use `sh` or `bash` for example